# Get textbox to show records of the same row of MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, database, textbox

I have the following code that when I fill in a name or whatever it may be, it will search through the MySQL DB and show me every name that has what you entered in it.

```
MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("Server=" + server + ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";");


            connection2.Open();
            string query = @"SELECT DISTINCT name2 FROM childDatabase WHERE name2 Like '%" + childSearch.Text + "%'";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection2);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection2);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);


                childSearchCombo.DataSource = dt;
                childSearchCombo.ValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
                connection2.Close();
```

Now, this code is fine and it is used for my comboBox.  The thing I need is that when you press the button (lets say... btnShow) it is supposed to display the rest of the retrieved from the db in the same row. Right now it currently just displays the index at [0] which is obviously not dynamic for each record and is the obvious flaw in the code that even I understand.

This is the code for it:

```
        MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("Server=" + server + ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" + database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Password=" + password + ";");

        connection2.Open();
        string query = @"SELECT DISTINCT name2, age, gender FROM childDatabase";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection2);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection2);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);


        firstNameDisp.Text = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        ageDisp.Text = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
        genderDisp.Text = dt.Columns[2].ColumnName;
```

So basically the last 3 lines of that code should display the name, age, and gender in the same row as selected in the comboBox.

I have searched for a long time and my knowledge just doesn't seem to be up to par yet. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `using` statement to properly dispose your MySQL objects.

This is a code snippet to get you started.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string _CS = "Server=" + server + ";Port=" + port + ";Database=" + database + ";Uid=" + uid + ";Password=" + password;
using (MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection(_CS))
{
    connection2.Open();
    string query = @"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM childDatabase";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection2))
    {
        // cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); There's no need to execute this. da.Fill() will 
        // execute your command.
        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            da.Fill(dt);
    }
    // connection2.Close(); No need to close either. The using statement does that.
}

foreach (var st in dt.AsEnumerable())
{
    if (st.Field<string>("name2").Contains(childSearch.Text))
    // or .Contains(yourComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        childSearchCombo.Items.Add(st.Field<string>("name2"));
        firstNameDisp.Text = st.Field<string>("your column name");
        ageDisp.Text = st.Field<string>(0); // or by index
        genderDisp.Text = st.Field<string>("column name or index");
        // Note that st.Field<T> also can be a decimal, a bool, an int etc..
     }
}
```

This way you don't need to query for every little bit. I'm also not 100% sure this will entirely work, i think you'll have to bug around a bit.

Anyway, probably there are many better ways to perform this. But i think it's a good learning curve. Good luck!

Comment: With a little bit of tweeking, this worked out. Thank you so much dude!